# Flutter release version apk shows black screen OR Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:profileRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: flutter

I'm facing the problem of black screen in the release version of the app, the debug version works properly. When I install and open the release version of the app on the phone, it just shows black screen and nothing else.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

While I was building the release version of the apk I was getting the following error

```
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:profileRuntimeClasspath'.
Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JetifyTransform: D:\MY_PROJECTS\flutter_projects\sabr_health_app\build\app\intermediates\flutter\profile\libs.jar.
> Transform's input file does not exist: D:\MY_PROJECTS\flutter_projects\sabr_health_app\build\app\intermediates\flutter\profile\libs.jar.
```

Comment: It happen to me too, in my case I need to add internet permission in androidmainfest.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` . After that I run `flutter clean` and then `flutter build apk --release`

Comment: @AldyYuan thank you for the response. I added it, still not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the reason for the error:

I had updated Gradle wrapper distribution version to `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip` in
`android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

AND

In `android/build.gradle` file,
I had updated `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'`

.

.

**Solution**

Reverting back to
`distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip`

AND

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'`

Doing this solved my error. I think there is some issue with the higher gradle version.

Comment: Hi Niteesh thanks for the workaround.But if any plugin which we are using in our project requires 4.0.0 then how we can avoid the black screen without downgrading

Comment: @RavishSharma that won't be the case, let me know if you face it with any plugin